# Concat for predefined macros

Tags: c++, macros

I would like to make single string from `__FILE__`, `__FUNCTION__`, and `__LINE__` predefined macros.

```
#define LOG_LINE __FILE__ " " __FUNCTION__ " " __LINE__
```

This probably will don't work because compiler concat don't work with integers which `__LINE__` is. 
    `#define LOG_LINE __FILE__ __FUNCTION__`

also don't work, because:
`error: expected ';' before '__FUNCTION__'`

How to achieve that to have
`std::cout << LOG_LINE` which will expand to e.g. `main.cpp main 8`?

Solution:
`#define LOG_LINE __FILE__ << " " << __FUNCTION__` does not satisfy me because sometimes I would like to use it as string (big macro with sstream also is not valid solution ;).

Comment: There´s no concept of integers in a `#define`. There are no types at all. And look at `#` and `##`

Comment: Yes, there are 'no concept of integers'. But they are AFTER. And compiler don't concat string with int but string with string yes. And why look at # and ##? To get string "`__FILE____LINE__`" :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following:

```
#define LOG_LINE (std::string(__FILE__ " ") +  __FUNCTION__ + " " + std::to_string(__LINE__))
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/xx7YrV)

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, could you explain what advantages this has over the 'unsatisfying' approach Senfen started with? You might not be able to concatenate the values you would need to create a constexpr string, but I don't see much of an aesthetic distinction here. It is faster than direct-to-stdout, but both can be improved: double buffer bottlenecking streams; sum the sizes as early as compile time and use one reserved string. This isn't a criticism, I just can't stand that the preprocessor and compiler. know the values but we need runtime calculations, heap memory, etc.

Comment: @JohnP: It could indeed be improved to be completely a compile time C-string. Difficulty is that `__FUNCTION__` is a `static const char*` (so preprocessor concatenation doesn't work and so it would require voodoo template) whereas `__FILE__` is a literal C-string.

Comment: That's really where we started, isn't it? I was saying that there are ways to mitigate or commute the costs, but that it was frustrating because the costs seemed artificial. Think of it in terms of ROI - you wouldn't be deterred by the lack of a free preprocessor function if you already determined that was where you needed optimization. I couldn't determine any other reason you would recommend adding strings over inserting streams. I only brought up variadic sizeof (free, CE) , etc. in case this was for performance, because it shouldn't be.

Comment: I'm not sure if you'd find this interesting or not, but actually determining/generating the function name is more intricate than I would have thought despite having most of the pieces of the puzzle. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Standardised_name_mangling_in_C++

The mangled names are incompatible by design to cause a linkage error *instead of a runtime error.*